# Curl failing with HTTP error 500

Tags: php, curl

Here is my code issued from `caller.php`

```
$data["names"] = $names;
$data["sizes"] = $sizes;

$destination =  $url.'/script.php';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $destination);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$pf = $data;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($pf));
curl_exec($ch);
$feedback = curl_getinfo($ch);
debug($feedback,"feedback curl");
curl_close($ch);
```

And here is the server structure

```
root
     /folder/caller.php
     /script.php
```

I can't decide to bring myself upon a conclusion of what might be wrong... I was trying to issue the curl request as a localhost but couldn't even do that. I just get a 500 and nothing more. Could someone please help me think what might be off?

Comment: 500 is a server side error, maybe your `script.php` doesn't work well .

Comment: Is $url defined? (Just for sake of thoroughness) - does "echoing" $destination result in a valid URL?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add user agent and referrer headers. Some times that is necessary to access.

```
 curl_setopt(CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://google.com');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
```

For test purposes remove that line and see if you get 500. I just ran into a problem that err 500 was raised when invalid header was passed to the curl. Fixing headers, fixed the issue for me.